# ActionCable vs Socket.Io is the most reliable and most scalable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, socket.io, actioncable

Which one is the most reliable and the most scalable?
ActionCable or Socket.io?

In order to avoid the opinion based answers please provide some real measured data which prove the hypothesis.

Are there any apps out there in production which were implemented using ActionCable, since ActionCable is out for a year?

Thx

Comment: have you found an answer ? share your experience please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Rails, ActionCable will be fine. It is currently used on [Basecamp](http://basecamp.com) and powers their chat and notification features.

This is a large scale application with heaps of daily active users so really you shouldn't be worried about scale. However, if you are talking about millions and millions of active connections, then probably neither is your best option - with the better alternative being Elixir/Erlang ([2Million Websocket connections in Phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org/blog/the-road-to-2-million-websocket-connections)) or even NodeJS.

However in your case if you are using a Rails application, then Actioncable is going to be much easier to implement as it is a feature of Rails and not an external party.

Comment: can you please provide some data to prove the hypothesis?

Comment: @boti what hypothesis is that?